# How to programmaticaly get nest auth PinCode?

Tags: c#, nest-api

Launching a browser session to https://home.nest.com/login/oauth2?client_id={your client id}&state=STATE, click on continue we can get the pin code.  As the web page using some binding, it's hard to programmaticaly mini it.  I tried post request, but couldn't go further. Does any one have a working (code) example of how to get the PinCode?

Comment: Here is a solution to host a web site within the app: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818265/NET-Works-with-Nest-Guide-to-calling-Nest-API-fro, but I don't like the approach.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically use the pin code to receiving the nest access token you must use a redirect URI. you can set it up via AWS, an insert the link in the nest developers account under redirect URI in the product you created.
NExt, follow the instructions provided by NEst LAbs in their github account: https://github.com/nestlabs/android-sdk.

good luck.